# Java, IntelliJ IDEA не работает класс

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Создал класс, но он не работает (Missing package statement: 'com.company')

```
class Test{
public static void main (String args[]) {
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

}

Comment: Если ошибка говорит, что чего-то не хватает, значит, нужно это что-то добавить/создать. Вроде бы здравый смысл должен подсказать, не?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно создать пакет и в него переместить этот класс. Или отсутствует объявление пакета перед импортами